# Can't reach out to nth child img inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this fiddle, I want to display only first photo on default and hide the rest, and change photo with each mousescroll. var i is determined by mousescroll, if i < 1 or i > 5, I want the operation to break because there is no nth child bigger than 5 or smaller than 1.

**Please provide fiddle in your answers. Thank you.**

**http://jsfiddle.net/a8FGe/6/**

```
$(window).scroll(function(event){
   var i = 0;
   var st = $(this).scrollTop();
   if (st > 0)
   {
       var i += 1;
       if (i > 5)
       {
           return;
       }
       $("img").hide();
       $("img:nth-child(" + i + ")").show();
   }
    else
   {
       var i -= 1;
       if (i < 0)
       {
           return;
       }
       $("img").hide();
       $("img:nth-child(" + i + ")").show();
   }
});
```

Comment: `display: hidden` is not valid CSS. Use `display: none;` or `visibility: hidden;`.

Comment: It's not going to solve your problem but you shouldn't be using `var i` each time, only the initial declaration, so `var i += 1` should be just `i += 1` (or simply `i++`)

Comment: @Exupery thanks for i++, I forgot that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

**http://jsfiddle.net/a8FGe/7/**

```
var i = 1;
$(document).bind('mousewheel', function (e) {

    if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0) { // scroll down
        if (i + 1 <= 5)
            i++;
        else
            return;

    } else {
        if (i - 1 >= 1)
            i--;
        else
            return;

    }
    //console.log(i);
    $("img").hide();
    $("img:nth-child(" + i + ")").show();
});
```